# SQL Server 2005 Inner Join Query

Tags: sql-server-2005, inner-join

I have two tables with a `Text` data type as the common field between them.

I have created this query in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table_A] A
INNER JOIN [Table_B] B ON A.[EmailAddress] = B.[EmailAddress]
WHERE A.[FieldA] = B.[FieldB]
```

There is 1 record on Table_A with email (someone@this.com) and 3 records on Table_B with email (someone@this.com).

When I run the query I was expecting 3 records in my result, but only get one.

Any assistance with what I am missing would be appreciated.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Maybe the where clause, cause the issue?

Comment: I have removed the where clause without success. In my opinion, the problem lies in using the [EmailAddress] as the common link between the two tables.

Comment: Check that values in your tables indeed match. Maybe there is a space character somewhere.